# How can I see SQL query received by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, profiling

Is there any way for me to see every SQL query string that is received by SQL Server?

My problem is: I deployed IIS server. I got errors like below when browse job by ID. I think the quick way is view the SQL strings sent to SQL Server.

But I didn't know how. Also I didn't see anything in Windows event viewer's app log.

> Stack Trace:
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at Unity.DataAccessLayer.GetUnityJobRaw(Int32 id) in C:\myrepo\HASH\myhash\hash\Unity\DataAccessLayer.cs:line 588
>          at Unity.DataAccessLayer.GetUnityJob(Int32 id) in C:\myrepo\HASH\myhash\hash\Unity\DataAccessLayer.cs:line 296
>          at Hash.Controllers.UnityJobController.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\myrepo\Controllers\UnityJobController.cs:line 128

Comment: You can use SQL Server Profiler tool to trace queries being sent to SQL server.

Comment: I didn't find it in SQL server 2008

Comment: Have you SQL Server Management Studio installed? Usually profiler comes with it. Run SSMS and go to Tools -> SQL Server Profiler. Or find `Tools\Binn\PROFILER.EXE` file in the folder of SQL Server and run it.

Comment: I didn't find it in SQL server folder either. Maybe my install is not full featured. I do installed SSMS plugin but not see the Profiler either. There's an item named SQL history under SSMS menu but it's blank when I click "search local SQL history".

Comment: Any step should be turn on first for the SSMS tool began to write log?

Comment: SSMS is not any kind of plugin, it is standalone application. You can install it either during SQL server installation or separately. Also there is no "SQL history" in it as far as I remember. So your environment is quite unclear for me and I can't guess what's going on at your side without seeing it, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You can trace every query or stored procedure with SQL Server Profiler

There is `profiler` in SQL Server 2008 also.

Please refer below link for that.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-sql-server-2008-profiler-complete/